# what is this weird icon in my taskbar?

Tags: xubuntu

This icon is on my taskbar (Indicator plugin) for a while now and I can't figure out what it is and how to get rid of it:

[image]

I'm using the latest version of xubuntu on a basic lenovo laptop.

Comment: Do you get anything when you click on it?

Comment: a tiny grey line appears next to it which might be a border of a tooltip that is supposed to be there but isn't.

Comment: I have one like that which is associated with my UPS. Apparently the status icon is missing or something.

Comment: If you can right click and do "remove from panel", and if you then add the "indicator applet complete" to the panel and it reappears - then I've got the same problem.

Comment: Are you installed Dropbox?